# Parse website data that requires interaction with a form (POST)

Tags: html, web-access

I want to analyse Chilean elections data available in the official website. What I have returns the data for president (numbers are strings, to be parsed later).

```
Import["http://www.eleccionservel.cl/ELECCIONES2013/vistaPaisPresidente", "Data"][[2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ;; 10, {1, 3, 4}]]
```

But to get the data for congress, the website does not have a direct URL and the data by districts needs to be selected by clicking in links that look like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:doSubmit('409','D');"> Distrito 9 </a>
```

Which in turn runs

```
function doSubmit(a,b){document.consultarForm.codigo.value=a;document.consultarForm.nivel.value=b;document.consultarForm.submit()}
<form id="diputado" name="consultarForm" action="/ELECCIONES2013/diputado" method="POST">
```

I have tried unsucessfully the following

```
url="http://www.eleccionservel.cl/ELECCIONES2013/diputado";
Import[url, "Data", "RequestMethod" -> "POST", "RequestParameters" -> {   "codigo" -> "409",   "nivel" -> "D",   "division" -> "POLITICA",   "codigoPadre" -> "409",   "codigoCircunscripcion" -> "409",   "codigoColegio" -> "D"   }]
```

Not sure if `"RequestParameters"` should refer to the "name" or the "id" of the form.

Is there a chance to get this data with *Mathematica* in an elegant and simple way, or should I be looking to a different tool?

Comment: (Nothing personal in flagging this question for closing. The issue appears to have more to do with an opaque Javascript-manipulated HTML form, not to do with _Mathematica_, in which your syntax was correct and fine.)

Comment: @acheong87 I guess the question was about finding a way around opaque Javascript-manipulated HTML form, using Mathematica. The solutions uses a non-documented feature and I thought I may have misunderstood it's use. Sorry if the question seems to be out of topic, it is my first post in here and I did try my best to apply due diligence.

Comment: No, in light of that view, your question may have been perfectly relevant—I'm new to Mathematica.SE myself and I don't pretend to have any authoritative view on this. That said, I'm doubtful _Mathematica_ should be able to help in that regard, because then _Mathematica_ would have to be able to not only _understand_ Javascript (a monumental task in itself, but then again, I may be underestimating _Mathematica_), but also _determine what code is relevant_. What happens, for example, if the website uses a complex jQuery extension to validate form fields before submitting the form conditionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code works fine—the site is just very stringent on the data supplied. I used Chrome's Inspect Element to see the values of all the input elements (including the hidden fields, as you'd noticed)—and I found that sometimes `codigoColegio` was left blank:

[image: Inspect Element]

It didn't work when I filled out `codigoColegio` to match `nivel` as you seemed to have done, but it did work when I followed the input fields exactly:

[image: Results]

(The copy-pasteable code is already in OP's post, so supplying a screenshot for convenience.)